# Four-current and identity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, dirac-matrices

I am studying QFT and I have found the following identity, which I don't know how to prove.
$$\bar{u}(p_{1})\not p_{1} \gamma_{\mu} \not p_{2}u(p_{2})=\bar{u}(p_{1})((q^{2}+m^{2})\gamma_{\mu}-2im\sigma_{\mu\nu}q^{\nu})u(p_{2}),$$
when $q=p_{1}-p_{2}$.

I tried to transform the left part to the right part  by use of
$$\{\gamma_{\mu},\gamma_{\nu}\}=2g_{\mu\nu}$$  and  $$\sigma_{\mu\nu}=\frac{i}{2}[\gamma_{\mu},\gamma_{\nu}],$$
but my attempts have failed.

Comment: By ${\hat p}$ do you mean $\slashed{p}$? Do you not have $\slashed{p} u(p) = m u(p)$?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: This would be the standard [Gordon decomposition of the current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_decomposition) in momentum space, but for the variables of the first term on the r.h.side. Can you rearrange?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. I must prove the identity without rearrange. :(

Comment: Are you using the identity $\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu= \eta^{\mu\nu}-i\sigma^{\mu\nu} $ properly?

Answer (score 0):

The familiar [Gordon decomposition of the bispinor current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_decomposition) is
$$
m^2~\bar u(p_1) \gamma^\mu u(p_2)=\frac{m}{2}\bar u(p_1) \left[(p_1+p_2)^\mu  +i \sigma^{\mu\nu} (p_1-p_2)_{\nu} \right]u(p_2), 
$$
equal to your left-hand side, by virtue of the Dirac equation and its conjugate,
$$\not p_2 u(p_2)= m u(p_2)\\
\bar u(p_1)\not p_1 = m \bar u(p_1)  .
$$

Note for $q=0$, so $p_1=p_2\equiv p$, the above reduces to
$$
m^2~\bar u(p) \gamma^\mu u(p)={m}~\bar u(p)  p^\mu   u(p),
$$
consistent with your ostensible identity. You might also use $q^2=-(p_1+p_2)^2+4 m^2$.

To be sure, you may use the Gordon expression to simplify your ostensible identity (conjecture?), to produce an equivalent expression,
$$
0= \bar{u}(p_{1})[(q^{2} )\gamma_{\mu}-2im\sigma_{\mu\nu}q^{\nu}] u(p_{2}),$$
your conjecture, but selective application of the Dirac equation gives me no confidence in the correctness of your coefficients.

A further equivalent form of this conjecture, gotten by subtracting the Gordon identity, is
$$
0= 
0= \bar{u}(p_{1})[-(p_1+p_2)^2\gamma^{\mu}+2m (p_1+p_2)^\mu] u(p_{2}).
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I get what you mean, but I don't understand how can I get the right side if I only know about the left side?  
I am apologize for not answering for a long time.

Comment: Where did the right side come from? The coefficient was off, which I corrected.